# Find the first that have most distinct digit by lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

Currently, I am learning the function of distinct() using in same lambda expression:
The first one is used for finding the distinct digit of an integer

```
Integer intVar = 12341234;
long c1 = intVar.toString().chars().distinct().count(); // (1,2,3,4)
System.out.println(c1);//result = 4
```

Then i want to try find the same thing within a range,
My thought is:

```
1.loop from 1 to 1_000_000
2.filter isSquareNumber && <= 9_999_999 && 1_000_000
3.convert to char
4.distinct
5.store as list(key,value)
6.findfirst key with value=7
```

Because the original code works but looks awful

```
int inte = IntStream.iterate(1, i-> i + 1)
        .filter(i->isSquareNumber(i) && i<= 9999999 && i>=1000000)
        .filter(i-> i%10!=i/10%10 && i%10!=i/100%10 && i%10!=i/1000%10 && i%10!=i/10000%10 && i%10!=i/100000%10 && i%10!=i/1000000%10)
        .filter(i-> i/10%10!=i/100%10 && i/10%10!=i/1000%10 && i/10%10!=i/10000%10 && i/10%10!=i/100000%10 && i/10%10!=i/1000000%10)
        .filter(i-> i/100%10!=i/1000%10 && i/100%10!=i/10000%10 && i/100%10!=i/100000%10 && i/100%10!=i/1000000%10)
        .filter(i-> i/1000%10!=i/10000%10 && i/1000%10!=i/100000%10 && i/1000%10!=i/1000000%10)
        .filter(i-> i/10000%10!=i/10%10 && i/10000%10!=i/100000%10)
        .filter(i-> i/100000%10!=i/1000000%10)
        .findFirst()
        .getAsInt();
System.out.println(inte);//result = 1034289
```

WJS helped version

```
IntStream
        .iterate(1, i-> i + 1)
        .filter(i->isSquareNumber(i) && i<= 9999999 && i>=1000000)
        .mapToObj(i->new String[] {Integer.toString(i), Arrays
                .stream(Integer.toString(i).split(""))
                .filter(a -> a[1].length() >= 7)
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(a -> System.out
                .println(a[1] + " --> " + a[1].length()));
```

It works wonderfully. And now I am trying to move one more step that creates a method in which the return type is an integer and returns the most distinct digit integer, but not a boolean.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the same thing within a range"? Can you give some example input and outputs, like you did with a single integer?

Comment: @Sweeper
input:1
output:1
input:12
output:2
input:121
output:2 // 1 appears twice , 2 appears once
and so on

Comment: @Sweeper
oh that means i want to do the same thing to all integer from 1 to 1000000 etc

Comment: Do you want to find the first numbers under 10 M that is a square and is comprised of seven different digits?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes,it is used to find 7 distinct digits,or even more,it can determine how many distinct digits at first and then store as an array or variable for further usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I limited it to the first 10 values.

- mapToObj creates a String array.
- the first item is the original value.
- the next one splits the string, eliminates duplicates and rejoins to a new string

```
IntStream.range(100000, 1000000).limit(10)
        .mapToObj(i->new String[] {Integer.toString(i), Arrays
                .stream(Integer.toString(i).split(""))
                .distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(""))})
        .forEach(a->System.out.println(a[0] + " --> " + a[1]));
```

prints

```
100000 --> 10
100001 --> 10
100002 --> 102
100003 --> 103
100004 --> 104
100005 --> 105
100006 --> 106
100007 --> 107
100008 --> 108
100009 --> 109
```

Find the first number that has 7 distinct digits.

After creating the arrays in the previous example, replace the `forEach` with a filter, followed by a findFirst, and then print the value if present.

```
IntStream.range(1000000, 10000000)
        .mapToObj(i -> new String[] { Integer.toString(i),
                Arrays.stream(Integer.toString(i).split(""))
                        .distinct()
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("")) })
        .filter(a -> a[1].length() >= 7).findFirst()
        .ifPresent(a -> System.out
                .println(a[1] + " --> " + a[1].length()));
```

Prints

```
1023456 --> 7
```

Comment: the part mapToObj does the work like List(key,value)?,then what if i want to .count() the value part to obtain the occurrence of unique number likes [input:12344321 , output: 12344321 -> 4 ]

Comment: oh btw thanks for teaching me a new way to use stream with in a stream,thats increase the flexibility

Comment: You're most welcome.  I presume that by 4 in your previous question you mean the number of distinct digits.

Comment: yes,i want to find distinct digits of integer and find first number that has to 1,2,3,...7  distinct digits and so on

Comment: oh,your code remind me that i forgot your a[1] is collected as String again and can be filter after .map().i am really new to multi layer of stream and array

Answer (score 1):

To find all numbers that are squares that have at least 7 distinct digits:

```
int[] all = IntStream.range(1000, (int) Math.sqrt(10_000_000))
    .map(i -> i * i)
    .filter(i -> Integer.toString(i).chars().distinct().count() > 6)
    .toArray();
```

To find just the first one (or explode trying, but there are 123):

```
int first = IntStream.range(1000, (int) Math.sqrt(10_000_000))
    .map(i -> i * i)
    .filter(i -> Integer.toString(i).chars().distinct().count() > 6)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

Rather than iterating over every number, I am iterating on the square root then squaring it, so it much more efficient.

Comment: oh man you solved my question perfectly,thank you so much